# CakePHP - paginate and sort 2nd level association

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

I understand that this has been asked 100,000 times but I've pretty much read all 100,000 replies and none of them seem to match what I'm after. I've tried every possible combination (obviously not) and I'm afraid I'm getting beat at something so relatively simple. This is my 2nd Cake project, so I'm by no means an expert.

Profile -> **BelongsTo** -> Store, Store -> **BelongsTo** -> Region, Region -> **HasMany** -> Stores

**Profile**.php

```
class Profile extends AppModel {  
public $belongsTo = array(
            'Store' => array(
                'className' => 'Store',
                'foreignKey' => 'store_id'....
```

**Store**.php

```
class Store extends AppModel {
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Region' => array(
            'className' => 'Region',
            'foreignKey' => 'region_id'....
```

**Region**.php

```
class Region extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
        'Store' => array(
            'className' => 'Store',
            'foreignKey' => 'region_id'....
```

**ProfileController**.php

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array('Profile.job_title_id' => '1'),
    'contain' => array(
        'Store'=> array(
            'Region'
        )
    )
);
$UserArds = $this->Paginator->paginate('Profile');
$this->set(compact('UserArds'));
```

**view**.php

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Region.name', 'Region'); ?></th>
```

All I'm looking to do, is to be able to sort by Region name when using paginator. No matter what combination I use, I just can't seem to be able to sort Region.name. The `order By` clause is omitted with all other 2-level-deep associations but works fine any other time (with same level or 1st level).

Can anyone suggest a fix for this simple mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the SQL debug output, the regions are being retrieved using separate queries, that's how Cakes ORM currently works.

In your case there's a relatively simple workaround. Just [create a proper association on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly), for example `Profile belongsTo Region`.

Here's an (untested) example, it adds a `belongsTo` association with the `foreignKey` option set to `false` in order to disable the automatic foreign key generation by the ORM, this is necessary as it would otherwise look for something like `Profile.region_id`. Note that consequently the `contain` config has to be changed too!

```
$this->Profile->bindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array(
        'Region' => array(
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Region.id = Store.region_id')
        ),
    )
));

$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array('Profile.job_title_id' => '1'),
    'contain' => array('Store', 'Region')
);
```

That should generate a proper query that includes the `stores` as well as the `regions` table, making it possible to sort on `Region.name`. Note that the resulting array will be a little different, `Region` will not be nested in `Store`, everything will be placed in the same level, ie:

```
Array
(
    [Profile] => Array
        (
            ....
        )

    [Store] => Array
        (
            ....

        )

    [Region] => Array
        (
            ....

        )
)
```

Either you modify your view code accordingly, or you transform the retrieved data before passing it to the view. A third option would be to include a nested `Region` in the `contain` config, however that would result in additional queries that are totally unnecessary as the data was already fetched with the main query, so I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: That was fantastic mate! Worked like a treat. Although I did try that before, I guess I was doing it wrong. That'll definitely help throughout the project now. Cheers!