# CakePHP 3 - Paginate sortWhitelist doesn't support 2nd-level Associated Model

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I have an issue that I can't use the sortWhitelist in paginate to enable the sort function towards the "2nd level's associated model's columns. (it works with the 1st level associated model's). Let me describe it clearly:

**Table Background:**

- `Users`: `id`, `name`
- `Tickets`: `id`, `code`, `name`, `price`
- `TicketsDiscounts`: `id`, `ticket_code`, `user_id`, `price`

There is a default price in Tickets, and sometimes there are discounted tickets, offering a cheaper price.

**Wish to do:**

I am making the view page of `Tickets`, which doesn't only show the `Ticket` itself's data, also a table showing

- `TicketDiscounts` records where`Tickets.ticket_code = Tickets.code`, and
- `Users` records where `TicketDiscounts.user_id = Users.user_id`.

**Issue:**

It actually works fine, til I want to add some sort functions for the table.
I know there is a config key called `sortWhitelist`, but in this case it only supports "linking" `TicketsDiscounts`.

Like:

Tickets---->TicketsDiscounts    [OK]
Tickets---->TicketsDiscounts---->Users [NOT OK]

In `TicketsController.php`:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $ticket = $this->Ticket->get($id);
    $setting = [
        "sortWhitelist" => [
            "Users.id", "Users.name", "TicketsDiscounts.price"
        ]
    ];
    $paginate_discountsowners = $this->paginate(
        $this->Tickets->TicketsDiscounts
            ->findByTicketsCode($ticket->code)
             ->contain("Users"), $setting
    );
    $this->set('paginate_discountsowners', $paginate_discountsowners);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['paginate_discountsowners']);
}
```

In `view.ctp`:

```
<td><?= $this->Paginator->sort("id", "User ID", ["model" => "Users"]) ?></td>
<td><?= $this->Paginator->sort("name", "User Name", ["model" => "Users"]) ?></td>
<td><?= $this->Paginator->sort("price", "Discount Price", ["model" => "TicketsDiscounts"]) ?></td>
```

**Researched:**
[CakePHP - paginate and sort 2nd level association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958410/cakephp-paginate-and-sort-2nd-level-association) <-- This one is very close, but its CakePHP 2.x, I read it but hardly found this post useful for my case.

[Pagination Sort in Cakephp 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948164/pagination-sort-in-cakephp-3-x) <-- This is 3.x, well, but it is about 1-level associated model only.

Thank you for reading my post, **any ideas are welcomed**.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over something similar. I have the structure `Teachers` -> `Users` -> `Persons` and want to sort by the person's forename.

**TeachersController**:

```php
public $paginate = ['sortWhitelist' => ['Persons.forename']];
```

**View**:

```php
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('Persons.forename') ?>
```

So, in short I think you can just have to change your first and second sort links to refer to the fields `Users.id` and `Users.name`.